# undefined is not a function(evaluation 'object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arguments[i])')

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run an app which I take from git. I ran **npm install** and **react-native run-android** then it occurred an error:

[image]

I have found solution on Internet for 2 days but there is no result. Can anyone fix this error please?

Answer (score 0):

There's an actual workaround for this, and it worked for me. Try to activate `Debug Js Remotely` on your developer options, Reload and your app will work. As I said it's a work around, but you can continue working on your app